# How to find internal vertices in variable-length-edges on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I tried to find internal vertices in variable-length-edges on AgensGraph.

But, It returns error message like following.

Is there problem on CYPHER query on mime?

How can I view internal vertices of VLE?

Attaching sample script follow.

```
create graph vle;
create vlabel o;
create vlabel l;
create elabel e;
create property index on o ( id );
create property index on l ( id );
create property index on e ( id );
create (:o{id:1})
create (:o{id:2})
create (:o{id:3})
create (:o{id:4})
create (:o{id:5})
create (:o{id:6})
create (:o{id:7})
create (:o{id:8})
create (:o{id:9});
match (o:o) create (:v{id:o.id});
match (n:v) where n.id >= 1 and n.id <= 9
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+9});
match (n:v) where n.id >= 11 and n.id <= 99
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+9});
match (n:v) where n.id >= 111 and n.id <= 999
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+9});
match (n:v) where n.id >= 1111 and n.id <= 9999
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'v:'+n.id+'->v:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:v{id:n.id*10+9});
match p = ( (v1:v{id:1})-[:e*]->(v2:v{id:11111}) ) return nodes(p);
ERROR:  graph path and variable length edge cannot be used at the same time
LINE 1: match p = ( (v1:v{id:1})-[:e*]->(v2:v{id:11111}) ) return no...
              ^
```

Please, help...

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get nodes between VLE path on older version of AgensGraph.

Think upgrading version of AgensGraph.

```
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens =# match p = ( (v1:v{id:1})-[:e*]->(v2:v{id:11111}) ) return nodes(p);
                                               nodes                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [v[6.1]{"id": 1},v[6.10]{"id": 11},v[6.91]{"id": 111},v[6.820]{"id": 1111},v[6.7381]{"id": 11111}]
(1 row)
```